# The rough average of searches needed, to find key out of n keys

Tags: probability, statistics

I've a question that has been bothering me regarding combinatorial searches, such as brute force of a key for an encryption.

Lets say I have 2^32 keys in a key space that would need to all be calculated to get a 1:1 probability of guessing the correct key. Would on average 2^32/2+1 random key searches be required to find the correct key?

My memory is leaving me about the above and what is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean rank of a given element of an ordered set of n to which one applied a uniformly distributed permutation is (n+1)/2. In your case you need to examine 2^(31)+.5 keys on average.